# List of styles in Material Design Colors and Themes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design

I try to create my first c#/wpf/xalm project using Material Design Colors and Themes. I have some tutorial where are defined some styles e.g. for `checkboxes` are:

```
Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignActionDarkCheckBox}
Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignActionLightCheckBox}
for Buttons Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}"
```

etc.

My question is: where I can find list of all available styles in Material Design?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you mean this:
http://materialdesigninxaml.net/

You can pull the source and take a look at it:
https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit

You can just take a look round on the site for a fair bit of what I should think you want.

https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/tree/master/MaterialDesignColors.Wpf/Themes

Answer (score 5):

The complete list of all the available styles is in MDIX wiki, ordered by control. No need to browse the XAML source code by control:

https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/ControlStyleList